# ASP .NET не находится файл

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net, iis-express

Я хочу с помощью GET запроса выдать файл пользователю.

```
        string sn = Request.QueryString["sn"];
        string folder_name = Request.QueryString["folder_name"];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sn) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(folder_name))
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 400;
            return;
        }

        bool b = File.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath($"/Files/{folder_name}/{sn}.zip"));

        if (b)
            Response.TransmitFile($"/Files/{folder_name}/{sn}.zip");
```

folder_name и sn берутся из GET запроса, они правильно записаны, но File.Exist возвращает false. Но если вручную в коде прописать значения, то все работает, как и задумано. Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath($"~/Files/{folder_name}/{sn}.zip");
```

Нужно было поставить знак тильды (~) перед началом пути к файлу.